# in joomla mvc how to Disable particular field only in edit view?

Tags: joomla

When I add disabled attribute in xml file which is in site/administrator/components/com_users/models/forms/ directory its effecting to both create page view and edit page view. what I am expecting is I just want to disable only particular fields in edit page..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy setting for that.

I probably would add a class to the fields in question and then add a small javascript in my edit-view which disables the fields with that particular class after rendering.
Something like:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    jQuery('.disableInEdit').attr('disabled','true');
});
```

OR:

You also could build your own fields which take xml attributes like `disabledInView="edit"`, but that is a bit more tricky I guess, especially if it ain't the simple field types.